# How to get the exact date from timezones

Tags: php, timezone

```
2016-12-14T14:00:00-08:00
```

the above is the time format that i get from google calendar  and the time zone is canada.

The time according to google is 5:00 Pm.
Can someone please help me to get the exact date and time from the above format in php???

Comment: Canada has [many time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Canada).  *Where* precisely in Canada?  Also, what have you tried?  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Comment: I am sorry for the incomplete question Matt.
I am using canada/eastern.
I tried converting the above given format to string to time.

Answer (score 1):

use [**date_default_timezone_get**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

get default timezone

```
echo 'get default timezone: ' . date_default_timezone_get();
```

set time zone of canada

```
date_default_timezone_set('Canada/Central');
```

Comment: Hi @Dave
I did change my timezone and used the below code

Comment: Hi @Dave i did change my timezone and then tried the following code

    `foreach ($events['items'] as $key => $value) {
         $roomavailable[$singleitem['id']]['events'][$value['id']]['start_date']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($value['start']['dateTime'])); 
          $roomavailable[$singleitem['id']]['events'][$value['id']]['end_date']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($value['end']['dateTime'])); 
                        }`

Comment: But got the ans as:
And got the result as:
    `[ejlk2brp2e2nk9oe0n1u6nga28] => Array
                        (
                            [start_date] => 2016-12-14 16:00:00
                            [end_date] => 2016-12-14 17:00:00
                        )

                    [73hhg2h2uru8g2tdr11igc700k] => Array
                        (
                            [start_date] => 2016-12-15 06:00:00
                            [end_date] => 2016-12-15 07:00:00
                        )`